# Como encontrar uma palavra nessa query params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs

Estou fazendo uma query que realiza `where` com base na string `filter` recebida no query params. O meu filter query params possui esse formato:

```
filter: (status~contains~false~and~username~contains~'admin')
```

Eu preciso fazer um `search()` nesse `request.input('filter')` e procurar a palavra contida após o `~contains~'palavra'` para fazer minha query. Estou com dificuldades de fazer esse regex. (Ainda não tenho certeza se regex seria a forma de resolver o problema, mas acredito que seja o caminho.)

Eu teria algo como:

```
 if(request.input('filter').search('regex??'))
            queryUsers.where('username', 'like', '%'+request.input('username')+'%')
```

@Edit:

o que eu estou tentando fazer é filtro condicional, em uma pesquisa de usuários eu posso pesquisar por username e status, o frontend retorna essa query string e eu preciso verificar se existe username no filtro, se existir, preciso desses valores pra colocar no where, atualmente minha função está dessa forma:

```
async index({request}) {
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const queryUsers = User
        .query()
        .with('user')

    let filter = request.input('filter')
    if(filter.search("username")){
        let userName = filter.replace(/(?<=')(.*?)(?=')/g, '')
        console.log(userName)
        queryUsers.where('username', 'like', '%'+userName+'%')
    }

    const users = await queryUsers.paginate(page, pageSize)

    return users
}
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro sua pergunta, vc precisa de qual parte da string?

Comment: @LeAndrade editei a pergunta, veja se ficou melhor de entender

Comment: Mas, pelo exemplo que deu **status~contains~false~and~username~contains~'admin'**, vc precisaria pegar a palavra `'admin'`?

Comment: isso, correto. :)

Comment: Mas a sua regex já está fazendo isso.

Comment: na verdade eu preciso do inverso do que eu fiz, porque dessa forma eu estou substituindo o valor que está entre ' ' por vazio, então fica tudo menos o que eu preciso. E quando não for uma string e um booleano, que é o caso do status, essa lógica não vai funcionar

Comment: Mas status tbm vai poder ter aspas?

Comment: não, por isso essa lógica não funciona pra mim, e também se tivesse mais de uma string acho que estragaria :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra quem precisar, eu consegui resolver desta forma:

```
async index({request}) {
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const queryUsers = User
        .query()
        .with('user')

    let filter = request.input('filter')
    if(filter.search("username")){
        let userName = filter.match(/(?<=username~contains~').*?(?=')/)
        queryUsers.where('username', 'like', '%'+userName[0]+'%')
    }
    if(filter.search("status")){
        let userStatus = filter.match(/(?<=status~contains~)[^~)]+(?=[~)])/g)
        queryUsers.where('status', '=', userStatus[0])
    }

    const users = await queryUsers.paginate(page, pageSize)

    return users
}
```

Desta forma eu pego o valor de uma string e booleano contida através da minha query param.